# Appending data with columns that have similar names using pattern matching

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr, stringdist

**I have five excel files with 2 sheets per file.**

-file_2015: a, b

-file_2016: a, b

-file_2017: a, b

-file_2018: a, b

**Both sheets a and b provide the same data over time.** 
They vary in the number of columns because new indicators are added to
newer files that do not exist in older ones.

The column names change slightly and I would like to consolidate this data by appending it together.

*Examples of variable names that are similar:*

-Metric Rating - Unit level, Percentage Earning 5 Credit in Third Year

-Metric Rating - 5 Credits in 3rd Year - Unit level

*The other problems I am running into is the fact that the same indicators from different files have been named with the corresponding year. For example:*

-Target For 2016 - Grad Rate, 6-Year

-Target For 2017 - 6-Year Grad Rate

Although they are the same data indicator, it is producing two columns when appending data.

Currently, I am using this function to read in all of the excel files and append each sheet data together as one dataframe.

```
df<-list.files(path = filepath_raw_data, full.names = TRUE, pattern = "*.xlsx") %>%
    #Keetping the names of the filepath as a data columns
  set_names(nm = (basename(.) %>% tools::file_path_sans_ext())) %>%
  map_df(readxl::read_excel, sheet=sheet_name, col_types = "text",  .id="file_name")
```

**Is there any way I can use pattern matching to match similar columns names together and append the data together?**

Comment: If you can come up with a bunch of regex rules to bin the columns together like `grepl("Target") & grepl("Grad Rate") & grepl("6-Year")` then it's relatively straightforward, but tedious, to rename the columns consistently using `mutate` before binding them together. If you're asking how to automatically link columns with somewhat similar names, that's much harder.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I decided not to use grepl is that I have about 100+ different variables in the same situation. I am trying to figure out way to automatically link the columns with a similar name using RecordLinkage or stringdist.